# Cant start mysql and cant find mysql.sock

Tags: mysql

I am on Cento 6.9 and trying to solve a problem with Mysql.

When I try to start mysql I get:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

As per recommendation of gurus here I tried to find mysql.sock file. I have tried:

```
find . -name mysql.sock
```

But could not find anything. Any idea where my mysql.sock is?

I have also tried:

```
lsof -U -c mysqld -a
```

which returns nothing.

Comment: `sudo find / -name mysqlsock`, but I doubt if it'll be there as the mysql daemon isn't working!   What is the command you are issuing to start mysql?

Comment: are you sure mysqld is actually running? what is the output of `ps aux|grep mysql`

Comment: This is the output: 
root      1484  0.0  0.0 112660   976 pts/0    S+   17:18   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql

Comment: From that output, mysql isn't running; how are you trying to start it? If you can put your cnf file could help

Comment: This is how I try to start it: # mysql start and I get : ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Answer (score 2):

Checks:

1. Is the server actually running locally?
2. Grep for `mysql.sock` in `my.cnf` and provide results
3. Run: `sudo /usr/sbin/lsof  | grep mysql.sock`
4. Check (i.e. `grep`) `mysqld` err logs to see if its remarking about `mysql.sock` or any other startup issues.
5. Check permissions on the MySQL directories, i.e. `/var/lib/mysql/` should be read/writable by the `mysql` group and sufficient permissions for users to reach the socket file.
6. How are you starting the mysqld process? The error looks more like a client connection issue?

While you can re-install solutions I have used in the past include:

1. Touch the socket file and make sure it is owned by the mysql group and user.

   ```
   ls -l /tmp/mysql.sock
   srwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql 0 Jun 15 15:08 /tmp/mysql.sock
   ```

   Check the `my.cnf` for the setting for where the socket is.

   You can use the following steps to re-create the socket. Just change the name to reflect the expected name of the socket as given by `my.cnf` under the `[mysqld]` and `[client]` sections.

   ```
   sudo touch /tmp/mysql.sock
   sudo chown mysql:mysql /tmp/mysql.sock
   sudo chmod 0777 /tmp/mysql.sock
   ```
2. Starting `mysqld` as a service via `systemctl mysql start` etc.
3. Make sure you are using `sudo` etc. as most command require root level privileges to work correctly.

Comment: I reinstalled the whole mysql now and I can see mysql.sock inside mysql folder. It wasn't there before. So for it has happened twice and I only restore the database by reinstalling mysql altogether.

Comment: @user7432810 I've added some more information that may be helpful in future.   I realise it will be unlikely that you can provide more information after re-installing however.